# PHP build array after query for template

Tags: php

Query back data, example:

```
| name_1 | name_2 | value_1 | value_2 |  obj  | i_id | // <- cols name
--------------------------------------------------     
|   BB   |   AA   |   3     |    6    | obj_1 |   1  |
|   BB   |   AA   |   2     |    1    | obj_2 |   1  |
|   BB   |   AA   |   2     |    4    | obj_3 |   1  |
|   CC   |   DD   |   3     |    3    | obj_1 |   2  |
|   CC   |   DD   |   2     |    3    | obj_2 |   2  |
and more...
```

Here I need to build an array for template, example:

```
$arr = array();
while($r = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) {
    $arr = ?   <---------------------  // HELP WITH BUILD ARRAY HERE!
}
```

Here is the template that I need, example:

```
<?php foreach(): ?> ------ // for each i_id 
    <?php if(obj == 'obj_1'): ?> // WE NEED obj_1 VALUES FOR CHOICE BOLD COLOR

        <?php if(value_1 > value_2): ?> 
           <?php $name_1_BOLD = "style='color: black;'" ?>
        <?php else: ?>
           <?php $name_2_BOLD = "style='color: black;'" ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

<div <?php echo $name_1_BOLD; ?>>   // ------  here can be bold color
    <?php echo $name_1; ?> --------- // here pass NAME 1
</div>

<div>
    <?php foreach(): ?>  //  ------  all values for each i_id
        <div>
            <?php echo $value_1.' - '.$value_2; ?> // here pass ALL VALUES FOR unique i_id
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
<div <?php echo $name_2_BOLD; ?>>   // ------  here can be bold color
    <?php echo $name_2; ?> --------- // here pass NAME 2
</div>
```

Guys please help me with it or provide any good guide. 
update:

[image]

from image 2-3 (3-6 from table) BB bigger than AA and have bold color and other

Comment: there are unnecessary closing and opening <?php ?> tags on this code. First clear them for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need an array of arrays.

The first array is an associative one where the key will be the identifier in your DB (`i_id`). And the value will be the rest of the data for that row (`name_1`,`name_2`, etc)

Then you'll iterate as you pretend retrieving each array and printing the contents.

With a bit of pseudo-code:

```
$arr = array();
while($r = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) {
    $key = $r->i_id;   <---the key is i_id, we will put the contents now..
    $arr[$key]['name_1'] = $r->name_1;
    $arr[$key]['name_2'] = $r->name_2;
    //etc
}
```

Your template (with what I think you want to do):

```
<?php 
    foreach($arr as $r)// for each i_id 
    {
       if($r->obj == 'obj_1')// WE NEED obj_1 VALUES FOR CHOICE BOLD COLOR
           if($r->value_1 > $r->value_2)
             $$name_1_BOLD = "style='color: black;'";
        else
              $name_2_BOLD = "style='color: black;'";

      echo $name_1_BOLD;   // ------  here can be bold color
      echo $name_1; // here pass NAME 1

      echo '</div>
        <div>
        <div>';
      echo $r->value_1.' - '.$r->value_2; // here pass ALL VALUES FOR unique i_id
      echo '</div>
         </div>
        <div ';
     echo $name_2_BOLD; // ------  here can be bold color
     echo $r->name_2;  // here pass NAME 2
     echo '</div>';
    }
?>
```

A side-note, notice you are abusing of opening/closing `<php` tags

Another: I'm likely printing more `div` tags that you want, you'd want to control this.

Comment: thats i know, i have problems with when i try make bold color can u make more example please or full it))?

Comment: mm, that's not clear to me. Do you mean 'obj_1' as the first element of your array? What is `obj` and `obj_1`?

Comment: **obj** it's name of col from table when foreach found it we try to make bold color

Answer (score 0):

It's bad practice to echo HTML code via PHP.  You should eliminate the need to integrate HTML code in PHP.  It is also a way of easily manipulating the styling on your page.

```html
<?php foreach($arr as $r): ?>
    <?php if($r->obj == 'obj_1'): ?>

        <div style="<?php if($r->value_1 > $r->value_2): ?>color: black<?php else: ?>color: red<?php endif; ?>">
            <?php echo $r->name_1; ?>
        </div>

    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<div>
    <?php foreach($arr as $r): ?>
        <div>
            <?php echo $r->value_1; ?> - <?php echo $->value_2; ?>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve with name_2...

Comment: i was edit the post you can look at image what i trying to make and why i need name_2...